# How to type square brackets in VirtualBox on a Mac

Tags: macos, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I am wondering how to type square brackets into VirtualBox (Guest OS is CentOS 6.3) on a Mac.

I know it's <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> on the Host OS, but it doesn't work in VirtualBox for some reason.

I use `be` layout for CentOS, keytable being equal to `be-latin1` and my host uses Belgian AZERTY.

Comment: Maybe there are some helpful tips on [this wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KEYMAP) to help you further?

Answer (score 1):

Since the layout on MacOS and Windows (and other OS) differs a bit.

On Windows/Linux the Belgian AZERTY-layout puts [ and ] on the two keys on the right side next to <kbd>P</kbd>.

Based on what you say, Apple uses the French layout for there Belgian layout...

So try <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> for [ and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> for ].

Hope this helps!
/marcus

Reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY